# Synaptic can't find firmware-b43-installer

Tags: wireless, broadcom, synaptic

I recently installed Xubuntu on a Dell Latitude D630 and I had to install drivers for a Broadcom bcm4311 card. I downloaded b43-fwcutter and firmware-b43-installer on my other computer and put them on a flashdrive to transfer. I extracted both packages and was unable to install them through the terminal so I installed Synaptic (via ethernet) and was only able to find and install b43-fwcutter in Synaptic. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In more recent Ununtu versions, the package is known as linux-firmware-nonfree. You may also need to rebuild the package index. Please try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and you should be all set.